# Correct way to implement django-widget-tweaks markup

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-widget, django-widget-tweaks

I am trying to render a form using django-widget-tweaks to help with css and widget types. I performed the following steps:

Install widget tweaks with pip3 in my venv successfully.

Put `'widget_tweaks',` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py.

Put the following in the template code. (The rest of the template tags render as expected).

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% render_field form.color0 type="color" id="color0" class+="input-color" %}
<!--replaces <input type="color" id="color0" class="input-color" />-->
```

My `<input>` element isn't rendering when I use the template markup (renders fine with static html, of course). The development server shows no errors, and if I print `myform.as_table()` in the shell it renders all the fields, so my `Form` object must be correct. What have I screwed up with django-widget-tweaks here?

Edit:
I also tried

```
{{ form.color0 | add_class:"input-color" | attr:"type:color" | attr:"id:color0" }}
```

I know the template engine is parsing it because if I deliberately misspel `attr` the webserver shows the error page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised that `form` wasn't instantiated until after POSTing (when I was debugging the request). Need to do something like:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    #process the form data
else:
    return render(request, "my_template.html", {"form":MyForm()})
```